# How to check entity framework performance difference between a join with any and a boolean check?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, query-performance

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what, if any, performance difference there would be between running a EF query like this

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(p => p.Photos)
   .Where(p => p.Photos.Any())
   .AsQueryable();
```

and this

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(p => p.Photos)
    .Where(p => p.HasPhoto == true) 
    .AsQueryable();
```

Will it be better to check for a boolean 'HasPhoto' on 'User' or will .Any() on a ICollection run fast as well on large data sets?
How can I check the speed diff, what tool?

Comment: Keep in mind that ```.Any``` automatically adds the overhead of getting the ```Enumerator```, calling ```MoveNext``` and disposing the ```Enumerator```. Take a look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont try it! You can use a timer to measure the time for booth. try using something like this

```
var watchOne = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
testOne();
watchOne.Stop();
var resOne = watchOne.ElapsedMilliseconds;

var watchTwo = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
testTwo();
watchTwo.Stop();
var resTwo= watchTwo.ElapsedMilliseconds;

public void testOne(){
    var users = _context.Users.Include(p => p.Photos)
    .Where(p => p.Photos.Any())
    .AsQueryable();
}

public void testTwo(){
    var users = _context.Users.Include(p => p.Photos)
    .Where(p => p.HasPhoto == true) 
    .AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: I don't have a large data set. Wouldn't only make any significant dif if the data set was large?

Comment: @user1186050 I dont think so, I would go with the `Any()` approach, but just because it's easier to read and more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Performance Considerations of Entity Framework as a whole:

1. Loading and validating data has a *Low*¹ **Relative Cost**.
2. Executing the query also has a *Low*¹ **Relative Cost**

¹[The total cost increases proportional to the number of objects returned by the query].

And considering that both

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(p => p.Photos)
   .Where(p => p.Photos.Any())
   .AsQueryable();
```

and

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(p => p.Photos)
    .Where(p => p.HasPhoto == true) 
    .AsQueryable();
```

return identical results, the actual return time would be a matter of milliseconds.

**However**, consider that the result set is relatively large, and consider the `.Any()` LINQ extension method

```
public static bool Any<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

and that this method does not return any one element of a collection. Instead, it determines whether the collection contains any elements (hence, decreasing total execution time).

So, ultimately, the `Any()` extension method will perform better.